# Printing a numbered list one item per line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a really long list in Python named `my_list`. I would like to print the contents of this list following these two conditions:

- One item per line.
- Each item needs to be numbered using three-digit numbers (e.g., 001, 002...)

This is my desired output:

```
001  csfiohfewiehns
002  hdifhdigbdgib
003  fdifhihiwhgighigh
004  jfjodopfhaeohgheg
```

So far, I have tried the following code:

```
print("\n".join.(my_list))
```

This worked and now each item appears in a new line. However, I still don't know how to number the lines using the format I want. I have heard of the function `enumerate`, though I don't know how it could be combined with my current line of code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to generate indices:

```
print("\n".join('%03d %s' % (i, s) for i, s in enumerate(my_list, 1)))
```

Comment: Oooh I was not aware that enumerate had a `start` argument

Answer (score 1):

Agree with blhsing, but since this case list comprehension's are faster, do:

```
print("\n".join(['%03d %s' % (i, s) for i, s in enumerate(my_list, 1)]))
```

Also got Mateen's this way:

```
print('\n'.join([f'{i + 1:03}  {x}' for i, x in enumerate(xs)]))
```

Or `zfill` as bhlsing's way:

```
print('\n'.join(['  '.join((str(i).zfill(3),v)) for i,v in enumerate(a,1)]))
```

Or as Mateen's way:

```
print('\n'.join(['  '.join((str(i+1).zfill(3),v)) for i,v in enumerate(a)]))
```

Comment: ditto number 3 for me

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use a for loop rather than making a new string:

```
my_list = ["abc", "def"]

for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
    print(f'{i:03} {item}')
```

This will output:

```
000 abc
001 def
```

If you don't understand some of the above code, leave a comment and I will clarify.

Comment: instead of using `counter`, getting the line number can be cleanly done with enumerate: `for i, item in enumerate(my_list): print(f'{i:03} {item}')`

Comment: what does the `f` within the print statement mean? @Loocid

Comment: @MeAll Its a format literal string, its telling python that the next string will be formatted so that you can put variables directly in the string. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest way:

```
'\n'.join(f'{i + 1:03}  {x}' for i, x in enumerate(xs))
```